# How to use Angular Cesium NOT in the root module

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I'm trying to integrate angular-cesium in my angular app.I have followed all the steps of [this tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cesium) *except* instead of importing `AngularCesiumModule.forRoot()` in my app module, I did this in a secondary module called `globe.module.ts`. In addition I placed the html and css in the secondary modules component `globe.component.ts`.

Everything seems to be working, the map exists in my dom, but it's tiny. I try to style it as suggested setting width and height along with setting 
`ViewEncapsulation.None` but this doesn't work. my map is still tiny. I have also tried placing the styles in my `styles.css` file with no luck

has anyone used cesium in a none root module or know examples of doing that? Do you know why my styles are not applying?
**UPDATE**

so I go the styles working by accessing .map-container, not #cesiumContainer like the docs... is this okay? id I integrate this incorrectly? I feel like the set up should be more than just including `AngularCesiumModule.forRoot()` in my globe component...

Answer (score 1):

The supposed role of `forRoot` method is incorrect. It is opposed to `forChild`, not to 'any module but top-level'.

As [the guide](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router) states,

> forRoot and forChild are conventional names for methods that deliver different import values to root and feature modules. Angular doesn't recognize them but Angular developers do.

And this guide chapter is dedicated to **lazy loading**. Lazy loaded modules have their own injectors, so `forRoot` initializes a module *for root injector*, and `forChild` does that *for child injector*.

Almost all third-party libraries don't need special treatment in child injectors and have only `forRoot`, and it is the one that is supposed to be used.

Generally `forRoot` is supposed to be imported once:

```
...
imports: [ModuleName.forRoot(...), ...],
exports: [ModuleName, ...],
...
```

And if there are other modules that should import `ModuleName`, they import it as is, without `forRoot(...)`. The actual use depends on what exactly happens inside particular `forRoot`.

[This article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f#4799) explains the situation behind `forRoot` and `forChild` in detail.

Comment: forChild() is not a property of AngularCesiumModule.

Comment: That's the point, *Almost all third-party libraries don't need special treatment in child injectors and have only forRoot, and it is the one that is supposed to be used*. I haven't seen any module but Angular router with forChild, because they don't need it.

Comment: so, Should I still import the module AngularCesiumModule.forRoot() in the app module, then import it in my globe module without for root?

Comment: You're importing modules only where you use them. If you're using it only in 'globe' module, you should use AngularCesiumModule.forRoot(), and don't mention AngularCesiumModule in app module. You need to do sanity check when using particular forRoot and check what it does. https://github.com/TGFTech/angular-cesium/blob/master/src/angular-cesium.module.ts#L157 . If you're not calling it, `config` service won't be defined and throw injection error. If you're calling it twice, you're overriding `config` service.

Comment: Thanks the downvote of correct answer. You are welcome.

Comment: sorry, too pre-emptive. still doesn't answer my question completely, but it was helpful

Comment: The problem you're having with Cesium styles has nothing to do with the subject. They are in fact two questions. I don't use Cesium, but as for modules, it's as simple as that. The only thing you can do here is to supply the configuration as `forRoot(...)` arg if it can affect the result, it's there exactly for it. I'd suggest to ask about specific problem with styles a new question and provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the issue you're having.